# Can't solve a find the missing number question

Tags: missing-digits

I found the following question on the [TORN forums](https://www.torn.com/forums.php#!p=threads&f=13&t=16018569&b=0&a=0), and haven't been able to solve it.

$$\begin{matrix}2&9&4&4\\6&0&3&0\\1&3&0&1\\0&5&7&3\\x&8&4&8\end{matrix}$$

My attempt so far

> I can see that $29$ and $44$ add to $73$, but I didn't get anywhere. I tried squaring the numbers, adding, squaring and adding, and a few other things, but I can't solve.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Usually we like some frame of reference from puzzles that you did not create. As in, can you provide a source? Also, in the future, try to hide your attempts as this should be a question to other users, instead of an open discussion on your progress.

Comment: @JasonV I found this [here](https://www.torn.com/forums.php#!p=threads&f=13&t=16018569&b=0&a=0). How do I hide my attempts?

Comment: see my revision. :)

Comment: @JasonV Okay. Done.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like

> addition of four four-digit numbers.

So the number is

> either 10 or 0, depending on what happens to the one that needs to be carried.

Comment: since it is asking missing digit, it is 0 :)

Comment: Wow! I didn't notice this at all!

Comment: @Oray Actually, the original puzzle doesn't say it's a digit; I guess that was just the closest available tag. (The original instructions are "After thriving in a couple of preceded defies, the king vouchsafes the next defy where [number grid]" which, er, ... yeah. They're all words, at least!)

Comment: All the other ones were carried to the next column, so it seems unexpected that the final one would attach itself to the x rather than simply overflow from the table.